# Ram usage of each script in a specific folder?

Tags: bash, command, ram

I have 26 Fvwm scripts in /home/amurt/.fvwm/core/. How to check the RAM usage of each one? Task Manager (xfce4-taskmanager), which shows the Ram usage that I am searching for but doesn't show all besides scripts that have a class name (FvwmPager, FvwmButtons, FvwmScripts, etc. What command to view all scripts in the folder?

Screenshot of Task Manager:
[image: Text]

Comment: `top` is capable of showing misc. statistics for processes.